# Is it possible to manually change viewport width to load a web page on android browser?

Tags: android, viewport

I'm trying to see a button on a mobile device which disappears on a display smaller than 1024px. I have no control on the web service so changing meta tag or source code can not be the option. Tried desktop mode with dolphine browser but didn't work. Simply want to load a web page as if it loaded on display bigger than 1025px.

I'm using Galaxy S7 ( viewport 414x732 )

Appreciate your help. thx.